# Zend - Recaptcha strange problem - working but not as expected

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, captcha, recaptcha

I have a bit of a strange problem. I am testing out Zend and needed to add a reCaptcha field to a form. I followed the example given in the Zend documentation it didn't work (getting used to that). Was getting the 'incorrect-captcha-sol' error.

After reading around for a while I finally managed to get it work. However it seems that the isValid method is returning the opposite from what you would expect.

Here is the code:

Form:

```
class Application_Form_Album extends Zend_Form {

public function init() {


    ## Set Recapture


    $this->setName('album');
    $this->setMethod('POST');
    $id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('id');
    $id->addFilter('Int');
    $artist = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('artist');
    $artist->setLabel('Artist')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('title');
    $title->setLabel('Title')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton');


    //Change theme
    $recaptcha = new Zend_Service_ReCaptcha("XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX");
    $recaptcha->setOption('theme', 'clean');
    $captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('challenge', array('captcha' => 'ReCaptcha','captchaOptions' => array('captcha' => 'ReCaptcha','service' => $recaptcha)));



    $this->addElements(array($id, $artist, $title, $captcha, $submit));
}
```

}

And the Controller method:

```
    public function addAction()
{



    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $form = new Application_Form_Album();
        $form->submit->setLabel('Add');
        $this->view->form = $form;
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

                $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
                if ($form->isValid($formData)) {

                    $captcha = new Zend_Service_ReCaptcha("XXXXXXX","XXXXXXX");
                    $result = $captcha->verify($this->_getParam('recaptcha_challenge_field'),
                                                 $this->_getParam('recaptcha_response_field'));

                    if ($result->isValid()) {
                        //ReCaptcha validation error
                        #echo "CAPTCHA FAILED!<br>";

                    } else {
                        $artist = $form->getValue('artist');
                        $title = $form->getValue('title');
                        $albums = new Application_Model_DbTable_Albums();
                        $albums->addAlbum($artist, $title);
                        $this->_helper->redirector('index');
                    }


                } else {
                    $form->populate($formData);
                }
       }
    } else {
        $this->_helper->redirector('index','auth');
    }

}
```

I would have assumed ($result->isValid()) to return TRUE on a valid captcha being entered. After some hair pulling I figured $result->isValid() is returning FALSE when captcha was successfully entered and TRUE if the wrong words or no words were entered?

Am I missing something? Anyone know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to create a new Zend_Service_ReCaptcha in your controller. The form should be taking care of it. Instead of `if ($result->isValid()) {`, try getting the captcha element from the form and seeing if THAT is valid. Take a look at the example in http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.captcha.operation.html

It might look something like:

```
if ($form->getElement('challenge')->isValid() {
```